# MongoDB aggregation. $group but also collect data on non-grouped fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a feature where users can post comments, and other users can post emoji reactions to comments.

Sample data for `db.emotes` :

```
{ "_id" : 'a', "commentId" : 'commentA', "userId" : "userA", "emote" : "emoteA" }
{ "_id" : 'b', "commentId" : 'commentA', "userId" : "userB", "emote" : "emoteA" }
{ "_id" : 'c', "commentId" : 'commentA', "userId" : "userC", "emote" : "emoteB" }
```

For `commentA`, 2 users reacted with `emoteA`, and 1 user reacted with `emoteB`.

Let's say `userA` logs in, so I fetch comments for the current view, and each comment's emotes.

```js
async listEmotesForCommentId (commentId) {
    const emotes = db.get().collection('emotes')
    return emotes.aggregate([
        { $match: { commentId: new ObjectID(commentId) } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$emote',
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                emote: '$_id',
                count: 1,
            }
        }
    ]).toArray()
}

//
const emotes = await listEmotesForCommentId('commentA')
/*
[
  { count: 2, emote: 'emoteA' },
  { count: 1, emote: 'emoteB' },
]
*/
```

Now, here's the problem. I want to have a field `hasReacted: <boolean>`, if the requesting user reacted to that comment. So now the function signature is `listEmotesForCommentId (commentId, userId)`, and my desired result is

```
const emotes = await listEmotesForCommentId('commentA', 'userA')
/*
[
  { count: 2, emote: 'emoteA', hasReacted: true },
  { count: 1, emote: 'emoteB', hasReacted: false },
]
*/
```

This result means that `userA` was one of the users who reacted with `emoteA`, and now my UI can display that. I've no idea how to do this with mongo aggregation. I wouldn't know how to do it with SQL either because once you group data, you lose access to non-grouped fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query :

```
emotes.aggregate([
  { $match: { commentId: new ObjectID(commentId) } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$emote",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      users: {
         $push: "$userId" // Push all users to users field
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      emote: "$_id",
      count: 1,
      /** Conditional check if pass'd in value 'userA' exists in 'users' array before assigning a value to hasReacted field */
      hasReacted: { $cond: [{ $in: ["userA", "$users"] }, true, false] }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4aQr32ieryy)

Comment: Yessss thank you. Works. So the key idea here is that I can collect extra, non-grouped data during the $group phase, and consume it in a later aggregation operation?

Comment: Btw, your answer differs from your link. `users` should be inside the `$group` object, that's what worked for me.

Comment: @EricGuan : Ohh sorry, typo while adding logic to your existing code :-) Yes you can do multiple things in group when it comes to `non-grouped data`, you can use `$addFields` instead of `$push` to store unique values in `users` array or you can use `$$ROOT` to store entire current document not just `userId` & many more..